# Writing to file using values from an object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4

My objective with this code is to use the foreach loop to go through each object and write the current string value to a txt file.

I'm using "Woof" and "Bull" as a test. Bull is the string variable in my AverageValues class.

Unfortunately, it currently will not write the value of bull to the file, however, it will create the file.

I think this is something easy to fix, I'm just can't seem to find it right now.

All help would be appreciated!

```
    public void doStuff()
    {
        AverageValues AVS = new AverageValues();
        AVS.Bull = "Woof";
        string path = "C:\\users\\kjenks11\\Averages.txt";
        FileStream NewFile = File.Create(path);
        StreamWriter writeIt = new StreamWriter(NewFile);
        List<AverageValues> AV = new List<AverageValues>();
        AV.Add(AVS);

        foreach (var value in AV)
        {
                writeIt.Write(value.Bull);
        } 
        NewFile.Close();
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to flush to write the data to the file. You also might consider adding using statements to your writer to free the resources when you're done.

```
public void doStuff()
{
  AverageValues AVS = new AverageValues();
  AVS.Bull = "Woof";
  string path = "C:\\users\\kjenks11\\Averages.txt";
  using (var NewFile = File.Create(path))
  {
    using (var writeIt = new StreamWriter(NewFile))
    {
      List<AverageValues> AV = new List<AverageValues> {AVS};
      foreach (var value in AV)
      {
        writeIt.Write(value.Bull);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.io.stream.flush.aspx) or close the stream before closing the file itself:

```
foreach (var value in AV)
{
     writeIt.WriteLine(value.Bull);
}
writeIt.Flush();
writeIt.Close();
```

Note on style - when creating a `Stream` (of any kind), or rather, any object that implements `IDisposable`, create it with a [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yh598w02.aspx):

```
using(var writeIt = new StreamWriter(NewFile))
{
  // use writeIt here - it will dispose properly
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `using` around your stream, there's no need to call flush and close explicitly. As soon as you leave the `using` block' scope the stream  will be closed and disposed. The close will call flush for you.

```
  public void doStuff()
    {
        AverageValues AVS = new AverageValues();
        AVS.Bull = "Woof";
        string path = "C:\\users\\kjenks11\\Averages.txt";
        FileStream NewFile = File.Create(path);
        List<AverageValues> AV = new List<AverageValues>();
        AV.Add(AVS);

        using(StreamWriter writeIt = new StreamWriter(NewFile))
        {
           foreach (var value in AV)
           {
                writeIt.Write(value.Bull);
           } 
        }
       NewFile.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You can use `using` on the FileStream like @EJC post, but at minimim I'd move the `NewFile.Close()` to below the `using` block.